# What is the role of using two dashes here __year in the example below ? im new in learning django

Tags: django, timezone, django-queryset

## Get the question that was published this year.

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> current_year = timezone.now().year
>>> Question.objects.get(pub_date__year=current_year)
<Question: What's up?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [**`__year`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) it thus filters on the `year` of the `pub_date`. It thus means that you will retrieve the question with the `pub_date` in the current year (2021).

Since you use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) this means it will raise an error if no such `Question` exists, or if *multiple* such `Question`s exist. You should use [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) to retrieve all `Question`s published in the current year (2021), this is thus a collection that can contain *zero*, one or *more* items.

Comment: yes thank you , these two dashes when we can use them aslo in django ?

Comment: @ChaimaeMsaad: those are *underscores*, you use these for lookups (like `__in`, `__lt`, __month`, etc.), and to look through a relation (so filter on the field of a related model object).